# Problemas com set_include_path()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Encontro dificuldade em fazer com que um único arquivo de configuração (responsável pelo `__autoload`) possa ser utilizado tanto pelos arquivos que estão na raiz, quanto pelos que estão na pasta `admin`.

O diretório raiz contém as pastas *`app`*, *`public`* e *`admin`*. A pasta **`app`** contém o arquivo de configuração e os diretórios *model*, *view* e controller.

Na pasta admin quero manter uma estrutura semelhante, com uma pasta app, contendo diretório *controller* e **view**.

O intuito é fazer com que os arquivos dentro de **`admin/app/controller`** acessem as classes por meio do arquivo de configuração contido em **`raiz/app`** e este seja o único arquivo responsável por incluir as classes. Para isto, utilizei a inclusão das pastas *raiz*, *`raiz/app`* e *`raiz/app/model`* via **`set_include_path()`** (utilizo o XAMPP).

Pois bem, se o arquivo está que chama a classe se encontra na *raiz*, ou na *`raiz/app/controller`*, a classe é instanciada, mas nada funciona na *`raiz/admin`*, ou *`raiz/admin/app/controller`*.

Para vocês entenderem como eu estava fazendo, eu tinha um arquivo de configuração para cada pasta, bem como um *app*, munido de *controller*, *model* e *view* para cada aplicação (horrível para dar manutenção) e funcionava.

Comment: É inviável fornecer uma "solução" pois necessita de mais detalhes, apesar de estar bem explicado, exige-se muito tempo para ler, reler e tentar interpretar tudo isso. Sugiro que procure padronizar o desenvolvimento de suas aplicações com normas como o PSR: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ .

Comment: Um amigo de trabalho estava com um problema semelhante pois o xamp dele tava desatualizado com o php ai tava dando conflito nas variáveis globais na hora de chamar as funções dentro de um diretorio pra outro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado adicionando constantes no arquivo de inicialização, contendo o caminho não só para o diretório com as classes, como para controladores e views.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    // um monte de instruções
    define('APP_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/');
    define('HOST_MODEL', APP_DIR . 'model/');
?>
```

Espero que ajude alguém.